# Need to save result as a PHP variable out the result of a MySQL SUM() query

Tags: php, mysql, sum, echo

I need to echo the result of my MySQL query, the query works.  Just complete mind blank into how to work out how to echo the result of it.

```
 $con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
 if (!$con)
   {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

 mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $con);

 $result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM($user_nameid) FROM profits");


 I KNOW SOMETHING GOES HERE BUT WHAT?! ANY HELP?


  mysql_close($con);
```

Thanks in advance, all help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`mysql_result`](http://php.net/mysql_result)

```
$sum = mysql_result($result, 0);
```

Comment: This is what I have been using however I get this error: Warning: mysql_result(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource.  Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: That normally means that your query wasn't right. Always check for errors: `mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());`

Answer (score 1):

```
    $con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
     if (!$con)
       {
       die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
       }

     mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $con);

     $result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM($user_nameid) FROM profits");

   $total = reset(mysql_fetch_assoc($result));

//comment this next line if you don't want to output to the browser
    echo $total; 

      mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: Thanks, im not getting my error anymore however whats the next command to echo this out? just need a simple variable ha.  Thanks,

Comment: if all you're doing is echo, just do this instead: if($result) echo reset(mysql_fetch_assoc($result));

Comment: Thanks, and to save it as a variable lets say $total?

Comment: Excellent, you have been a great help! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're getting at with the query. SUM() applies to a particular FIELD in the table you're querying. Most likely you'd want

```
SELECT count(*) FROM profits WHERE usernamefield='$username_id';
```

Note the quotes around the variable. If that variable contains anything that is NOT purely numeric, it must be quoted. And you must also take care of any SQL injection problems:

```
$username_id = $_POST['username_id'];
$safe_id = mysql_real_escape_string($username_id);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM profits WHERE usernamefield='$safe_id'") or die(mysql_error();
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$count = $row[0];
```

is how things should look.

Comment: I want to sum all the rows of a column where the header equals $username_id.  And then save the result as a variable. I still haven't found the solution I'm looking for. Thanks for the help tho!  If you have any further ideas, they would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you're creating a db column per-user?

Comment: yes, i have a user database with user data, but when an account is created, I have it adjust my db with + column with their username.  Then figures will be inserted into 'their' column. I need to sum these totals. Cheers for the help